# Connecting to neo4j from ruby

Tags: ruby, database, security, ssl, neo4j

Currently I'm having problems connecting to a local neo4j instance with Ruby. I have the mac version of neo4j desktop running. My ruby version is 2.6.5 and gem versions:
neo4j (9.6.0)
neo4j-core (9.0.0)
neo4j version: Neo4j Desktop 1.2.3 for Mac using Neo4j 3.5.12

Here is the code that I use;

```
user = 'neo4j'
pass = 'asdf1234'
url = "https://localhost:7473"
options = {user: user, pass: pass}

neo4j_adaptor = Neo4j::Core::CypherSession::Adaptors::HTTP.new(url, options)
neo4j_session = Neo4j::Core::CypherSession.new(neo4j_adaptor)
result = neo4j_session.query("MATCH (n:blah) RETURN count(n)")
```

The error I get is:

```
Neo4j::Core::CypherSession::ConnectionFailedError: Faraday::ConnectionFailed: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
```

When I add the no ssl option like this, the error is the same

```
options = {ssl: false, user: user, pass: pass}
```

When I switch to bolt like this:

```
require 'neo4j/core/cypher_session/adaptors/bolt'

user = 'neo4j'
pass = 'asdf1234'
url = "bolt://localhost:7687"

options = {user: user, pass: pass}

neo4j_adaptor = Neo4j::Core::CypherSession::Adaptors::Bolt.new(url, options)
neo4j_session = Neo4j::Core::CypherSession.new(neo4j_adaptor)
result = neo4j_session.query("MATCH (n:blah) RETURN count(n)")
```

The error becomes:

```
Net::TCPClient::ConnectionFailure: #connect Failed to connect to any of localhost:7687 after 0 retries. Net::TCPClient::ConnectionFailure: #connect SSL handshake failure with 'localhost[127.0.0.1]:7687': OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate)
```

When I switch the ssl false on

```
options = {ssl: false, user: user, pass: pass}
```

The error changes

```
RuntimeError: Init did not complete successfully

Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized
The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.
```

My graph settings are set to default with only these options being enabled:

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=512m
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=1G
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=512m
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+UseG1GC
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
dbms.jvm.additional=-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
dbms.jvm.additional=-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true
dbms.windows_service_name=neo4j
dbms.jvm.additional=-Dunsupported.dbms.udc.source=desktop
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: Hi @Lju I'm using Neo4j Desktop 1.2.3 for Mac

Comment: Thanks, within Neo4j Desktop, what version of the database have you downloaded/are running? You will see it on the Project page where you would start/stop the database

Comment: It is Neo4j 3.5.12

Comment: Just a random musing, using your first example, what happens if you change the url  from https to http

Comment: When I change the URL to http with same port I get this error: Neo4j::Core::CypherSession::ConnectionFailedError: Faraday::ConnectionFailed: No error

When I change the port to 7474(which is the http port) then I get: Neo4j::Core::CypherSession::CypherError:   Cypher error:
  Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized: No authentication header supplied.